# How To Know Which Link Clicked [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a webpage and i have a comment section in it , then i added a button that used for viewing the reply of the comments and when i click on the button that to show the reply , the button shows all the replays of the comments !

```css
$('.viewreplycommentbutton').click(function() {
  $('.reply').slideToggle(200);
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div dir="auto" class="usercomment">
  <content>
    <div class="usercommentcontent">
      <a href="" class="deletecommentbutton">×</a>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img id="usercommentimage" src="img/user.jpg">
          </td>
          <td class="usercommentusername">david jacson</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
      <div dir="auto" class="usercommentmsg">Thank You Very Much Bro.</div>
      <a class="tooltips viewreplycommentbutton" title="Black">+<span>See Replys</span></a>
      <div class="reply">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img id="usercommentimage" src="img/user.jpg">
            </td>
            <td class="usercommentusername">Michael Walson</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div dir="auto" class="usercommentmsg">Thanks.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="reply">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img id="usercommentimage" src="img/user.jpg">
            </td>
            <td class="usercommentusername">Michael Walson</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div dir="auto" class="usercommentmsg">Thanks.</div>
      </div>
      <br>
  </content>
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to be it , when i click the button of view the replys of specific comment , only the specific comment show the replys ( not all comments view the replys ! ).

Comment: How are these related, are the direct replies the next one in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer to the element being clicked and then traverse the DOM from there. Also note that IDs **must** be unique:

```
$('.viewreplycommentbutton').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.reply').slideToggle(200);
});
```

```js
$('.viewreplycommentbutton').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.reply').slideToggle(200);
});
```

```css
.reply {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div dir="auto" class="usercomment">
  <content>
    <div class="usercommentcontent">
      <a href="" class="deletecommentbutton">×</a>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img id="usercommentimage" src="img/user.jpg">
          </td>
          <td class="usercommentusername">david jacson</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
      <div dir="auto" class="usercommentmsg">Thank You Very Much Bro.</div>
      <a class="tooltips viewreplycommentbutton" title="Black">+<span>See Replys</span></a>
      <div class="reply">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img id="usercommentimage" src="img/user.jpg">
            </td>
            <td class="usercommentusername">Michael Walson</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div dir="auto" class="usercommentmsg">Thanks.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="reply">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img id="usercommentimage" src="img/user.jpg">
            </td>
            <td class="usercommentusername">Michael Walson</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div dir="auto" class="usercommentmsg">Thanks.</div>
      </div>
      <br>
  </content>
  </div>
</div>
<div dir="auto" class="usercomment">
  <content>
    <div class="usercommentcontent">
      <a href="" class="deletecommentbutton">×</a>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img id="usercommentimage" src="img/user.jpg">
          </td>
          <td class="usercommentusername">david jacson</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
      <div dir="auto" class="usercommentmsg">Thank You Very Much Bro.</div>
      <a class="tooltips viewreplycommentbutton" title="Black">+<span>See Replys</span></a>
      <div class="reply">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img id="usercommentimage" src="img/user.jpg">
            </td>
            <td class="usercommentusername">Michael Walson</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div dir="auto" class="usercommentmsg">Thanks.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="reply">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img id="usercommentimage" src="img/user.jpg">
            </td>
            <td class="usercommentusername">Michael Walson</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div dir="auto" class="usercommentmsg">Thanks.</div>
      </div>
      <br>
  </content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(this).attr("id") to get the id of the element that was clicked:

```
$('.viewreplycommentbutton').click(function() {
    var id_string = $(this).attr("id");

    // Prepend the id string with # to reference the object by name...
    alert("You clicked #" + id_string);
});
```